# How come my input is passing through the wrong if statement?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, numberformatexception

Input is a string s with value set as A

Also, note that X is a character and Y is an integer

```
if (s.length() == 1)
{
    X = s.charAt(0);
    Y = 1;
}
else
{
    X = s.charAt(0);
    Y = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
}
```

the length of A is 1, so shouldn't it go through the 'if' and not the 'else'?
I have tried with an 'else if; and 'if':

```
if (s.length() > 1)
{
    X = s.charAt(0);
    Y = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
}
```

When I use it in another class, it gives me an error of

```
NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"
```

Where am I going wrong? Is it in this if condition or am I going wrong in the other class?

Comment: "the length of A is 1, so shouldn't it go through the 'if' and not the 'else'?"
Don't you mean the length of `s` is 1? I don't see any `A` variables in the code.

Comment: I should have clarified that the value for s = A

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that there are no other whitespace characters in the string `"A"`? Some characters can add to the length of a string, though may not be visible when read by human eyes.

Comment: Try To print S and length before any processing and try. I think this is java. Then use System.out.println("[" + S + "]"). whitespaces will be visible.

Comment: The string '"A"' is from a test file that I'm not allowed to change. If there were whitespace characters, how would I go about fixing it? Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but '"A"' is the last element in a larger string that's being processed through the other class, could the whitespace be from there? Or is the error actually in the other class?

Comment: give the code where you are initializing `s`. @MarianaC

Answer (score 0):

Just a replica of your code to prove that your code has no error as it stands. There must be something else you are doing wrong somewhere else but not in the code shown here.

```
String s = "A";
char X;
int Y;
if (s.length() == 1) {
    System.out.println("'if' block executed");
    X = s.charAt(0);
    Y = 1;
} else {
    System.out.println("'else' block executed");
    X = s.charAt(0);
    Y = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
}
System.out.println("X = " + X + ", Y = " + Y);
```

Output to the console was:

```
'if' block executed
X = A, Y = 1
```